# creating an array in a seperate constructor class

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor

Very new to this.  I'm trying to call a constructor method out of a separate class file that will make an array.  Rather than post what I was working on for an assignment I've made a generic version that is much more simple.

What I am expecting is that the main will call MakeArray which will create an array of 3 integers: [0,1,2] then the main will add these terms and the only output would be the total, 2.

From my Main:

```
MakeArray trial = new MakeArray()   
System.out.println(trial[0] + trial[1] + trial[2]);
```

From my class file:

```
final int CONSTANT = 3;

public MakeArray() 
{
    int[] demo = new int[CONSTANT];
    for(int i=0; i<CONSTANT; i++)
    {
        demo[i]=i;
    }
    return demo[];   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can't use 'return' in constructor

Comment: You can't use an object as an array if it's not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an array like this won't work because arrays aren't normal objects but special ones. 
So you can't just make an object that works the same as an array, instead make a static method (one that can be called without having an instance of a class) and make it return an array, like this:

```
static final int CONSTANT = 3;

public static int[] MakeArray()
{
    int[] demo = new int[CONSTANT];
    for(int i=0; i<CONSTANT; i++)
    {
        demo[i]=i;
    }
    return demo;   
}
```

In that case you also have to make the constant variable static like I have done.
Then you can call this much like a constructor, you just need to add the name of the class it is placed in before it when you want to call it:

```
int[] trial = MakeArray.MakeArray();
```

This of course only works if you put this method in a class called "MakeArray" otherwise you have to put something else in front of the dot.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  A lot of great (and really fast) answers to my question.  I used this as a model and it has worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to want a new instance of a `MakeArray` I suggest you make it an utility method.

From my Main:

```
int[] trial = MakeArray.newArray(3);

System.out.println(trial[0] + ", " + trial[1] + ", "+trial[2]);
```

with a utlity class defined as

```
enum MakeArray { ;
    static int[] newArray(int n) {

        int[] demo = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            demo[i]=i;
        return demo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter!  This was my first time using this site by posting a question - the great and quick feedback is a huge help!

Comment: @theninja when posting a question, you get more credibility if you post code which compiles. It wasn't problem in this case, but a common mistake is to either a) not do a simple search for a solution before asking, b) use your debugger to debug a program first. (That is what it is for)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the MakeArray object as an array. You could however **create a method returns said array**:

```
class MakeArray {
    public static int[] makeArray() {    
        int[] demo = new int[CONSTANT];
        for(int i=0; i<CONSTANT; i++) {
            demo[i]=i;
        }
        return demo;   
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
int[] trial = MakeArray.makeArray();
System.out.println(trial[0] + trial[1] + trial[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to add an instance variable in your class and its corresponding getter method:

```
final int CONSTANT = 3;
int[] demo;

public MakeArray() 
{
    demo = new int[CONSTANT];
    for(int i=0; i<CONSTANT; i++)
    {
        demo[i]=i;
    } 
}

public getArray(){
    return demo;
}
```

Now you can call from `main`:

```
MakeArray arr = new MakeArray();
int[] trial = arr.getArray();
System.out.println(trial[0] + trial[1] + trial[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand your question, you may be want something like this.

class file:

```
final int CONSTANT = 3;

public class MakeArray
{
    public int[] demo;

    public MakeArray() 
    {
        demo = new int[CONSTANT];
        for(int i=0; i<CONSTANT; i++)
        {
            demo[i]=i;
        }   
    }
}
```

main class:

```
MakeArray trial = new MakeArray()   
System.out.println(trial.demo[0] + trial.demo[1] + trial.demo[2]);
```